# How do I use Material UI with Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am looking to use Next.js with Material UI with my React app. I have followed the [official Material UI Next.js exmaple](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs).

Although, when I try either run `next dev` or `next build`, the following error occurs.

I have run `npm ls react` to ensure I only have one version of `react`, and confirmed that `react-dom` and `react` were the same version (6.13.1).

It seems to be treating the `originalRenderPage` as a hook. Although, the official [Next.js documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document) also details the custom document page and has the same `originalRenderPage` within the class component.

[image]

I have tried converting the `_document.js` component into a functional component rather than a class, but it does not work.

The contents of the `_document.js` page (directly from the Material UI/Next.js example above) are:

```
import React from "react";
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";
import { ServerStyleSheets } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import theme from "../components/theme";

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
    render() {
        return (
            <Html lang="en">
                <Head>
                    {/* PWA primary color */}
                    <meta name="theme-color" content={theme.palette.primary.main} />
                </Head>
                <body>
                    <Main />
                    <NextScript />
                </body>
            </Html>
        );
    }
}

// `getInitialProps` belongs to `_document` (instead of `_app`),
// it's compatible with server-side generation (SSG).
MyDocument.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
    // Resolution order
    //
    // On the server:
    // 1. app.getInitialProps
    // 2. page.getInitialProps
    // 3. document.getInitialProps
    // 4. app.render
    // 5. page.render
    // 6. document.render
    //
    // On the server with error:
    // 1. document.getInitialProps
    // 2. app.render
    // 3. page.render
    // 4. document.render
    //
    // On the client
    // 1. app.getInitialProps
    // 2. page.getInitialProps
    // 3. app.render
    // 4. page.render

    // Render app and page and get the context of the page with collected side effects.
    const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
            enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />),
        });

    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

    return {
        ...initialProps,
        // Styles fragment is rendered after the app and page rendering finish.
        styles: [...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles), sheets.getStyleElement()],
    };
};
```

Comment: I forked the official example from [material-ui](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs), ran it locally, and it runs without problems. Which leads me to believe that this is a codesandbox only related error. On that note, make sure you're using at least node v10+ and react 16.10+ locally. In addition, the error stack trace can sometimes be invalid and point to the wrong file when there's an invalid import or invalid imported component module usage. That said, if you're still running into issues, post a github repo with a reproducible example.

Comment: On a related note, when I was making a codesandbox example, I noticed `useRouter` was not an export from `next/router` and was causing an error. Once again, this appears to be a [codesandbox only issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/15058)